# OracleDataReader Reader.Read() shows Enumeration yielded no results but has rows true

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I have one abstract method which returns oracle reader, I can see the rows in enumeration and has rows field set to true while debugging but when I reach to reader.Read() line it shows Enumeration yielded no results but has rows still set to true.

```vb
Dim reader as OracleDataReader = pobj_W.GetMyReader()
   
While reader.Read()
   //code
End while
```

finally got the access of the above abstract method which returns oracle reader

```
 Dim Cmd As OracleCommand = Nothing
            Dim reader As OracleDataReader = Nothing
            Dim sentCmd As Boolean = False
    
   If robj_Command Is Nothing Then
        Cmd = pcon_Conn.MyOraConn.CreateCommand
        Cmd.CommandText = vstr_SQL  
    Else
            Cmd = robj_Command
            sentCmd = True
        End If

        If pcon_Conn.QueryTimeout > 0 Then 
         Cmd.CommandTimeout = pcon_Conn.QueryTimeout

        reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If sentCmd = False Then Cmd.Dispose()
        Cmd = Nothing

        Return reader
```

It never goes inside the loop since Enumeration yielded no results. what is happening here?

while debugging, result view will show rows just for few seconds after that it gets empty but has rows still remains true.

Comment: A DataReader can only be enumerated once.  Are you sure you're not consuming the rows in the debugger?

Comment: Consider adding the content of the `GetMyReader()` function, the posted code looks fine so far

Comment: @Cleptus You fixed the reader syntax but left the // C# comment.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft what does that mean when you say - you're not consuming the rows in the debugger ?

Comment: @Cleptus sorry for the confusion, it is a VB.net code

Comment: I mean by examining the object in the Immediate Window or a Watch.

Comment: @Cleptus
have updated my question with the code inside that method which returns oracle reader. please have a look

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft just simple debug no watch, have also added the code inside that method which returns oracle reader. please have a look.